# Can HAProxy be used to limit number of incoming connections to frontent grouped by host?

Tags: haproxy

I know it is possible to limit the maximum active connections to a HAProxy frontent. However, is it possible to somehow also limit number of concurrect connections coming from a single host? I would like further connections to be queued up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haproxy can block by source IP based on different criteria (which could be mixed together):
number or rate of HTTP or TCP connections.
Have a look at stick-tables (and use HAProxy 1.5).

Some examples here:
http://blog.exceliance.fr/2012/02/27/use-a-load-balancer-as-a-first-row-of-defense-against-ddos/

Cheers